# loop over sequential column headers in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df where there are column headers like:

```
P5_14_01 : automovil 
P5_14_02 : colectivo 
P5_14_03 : taxi app 
P5_14_04 : taxi calle, sitio u otro 
P5_14_05 : metro 
P5_14_06 : autobus, rtp o M1 
P5_14_07 : bicicleta
P5_14_08 : autobus 
P5_14_09 : moto 
P5_14_10 : trolebus
P5_14_11 : metrobus o mexibus 
P5_14_12 : tren ligero 
P5_14_13 : tren suburbano 
P5_14_14 : caminar en la calle 
P5_14_15 : mexicable 
P5_14_16 : bicitaxi 
P5_14_17 : mototaxi
P5_14_18 : transporte escolar
P5_14_19 : transporte de personal
P5_14_20 : otro
```

words after colon are reminders (for me) to know which kind of information i'm dealing with, so they don't appear on df. For each one of those I want to loop and do some counting.
My question is, how can I do this, since each column header is a string, yet last cipher varies? In other words, if I want to do some things (same for all of them) on each column, how can I loop over them, being their "names" sequential numbers strings?

Any help is welcomed. Thanks.

EDIT: My df has much more columns than those i'm talking about, so I need a specific way to address those i'm interested in...which by the way are spread across the df.

Comment: If these are the columns of the dataframe, you can loop just like `for col in df.columns: df[col].do_something()`

Comment: "I want to loop and do some counting" sounds like you are missing some important dataframe concepts. You should ask another question on this.

Comment: Yes, im no expert on dataframe concepts at all. I just wanted to focus on loop over columns based on their names. What i want to do with each of them is already solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def column_funtion(col_data):
    pass

columns_of_interest = [f'P5_14_{i:02}' for i in range(1, 21)]
df[columns_of_interest].apply(column_funtion, axis=0)

# If you are interested to all the columns
# df.apply(column_funtion, axis=0)
```

For example, given:

```py
def column_funtion(col_data):
    return [col_data.max(), col_data.min(), col_data.mean()]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.random((10, 20)),
    columns=[f'P5_14_{i:02}' for i in range(1, 21)]
)
```

You will get:

```sh
   P5_14_01  P5_14_02  P5_14_03  ...  P5_14_18  P5_14_19  P5_14_20
0  0.916494  0.905081  0.829551  ...  0.869645  0.865701  0.914750
1  0.097684  0.010287  0.084090  ...  0.006364  0.052833  0.328201
2  0.498535  0.563385  0.487549  ...  0.552535  0.384080  0.603198
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. I have two questions: what does the f in f ' P5_14_{i:02}' stands for?, and...how can i implement your solution also in the function, I mean if in def column_funtion i have  df.apply(lambda row:(row['P5_14_01']==1)*row['FACTOR'], axis=1).sum(), where i need to run over same headers?

Comment: @JohnDoe `f 'P5_14_{i:02}'` is a [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), a way to format a string. For the other question I'm not really sure of what you would achieve: can you provide a more detailed example? Because in my answer function `column_function` was meant to be applied to each column, while in your example you are operating by row on different columns (e.g., `axis=1` in `apply`). If your aim is to sum `FACTOR` when the correspondent values in a column are 1, you can easily make it a column function: `df[col_data == 1]['FACTOR'].sum()`